# WinCE startup script

Tags: scripting, windows-ce

Is it possible to have it run at start-up a script? If yes, what should check when I am building the image, and what would it be developer's reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "script"?  What sort of script? If you have the command parser in the OS, then you can run a batch file.  You could also create a parser and have it do some work on a file at startup - sky's the limit there.

Comment: You are right, I want to run a batch file and I wasn't sure if it can be done.

Comment: So the answer is "yes, as long as the command parser exists in the OS"